# Jenkins pipeline push git tags from windows jenkins server

Tags: git, authentication, tags, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline, I need to tag on particular commit and push them.
on tagging to particular commit is done because it tag on local repository. But when I tried to push to remote it stuck.

After research I found that it required Authentication from my server to push --tags to remote.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'd3e19626-62d7-4acc-8090-1b0f39fdfc47', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
    bat "git tag Jenkins_build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
    bat "git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@git.ABC.com:8443/ABC/ABC-dev.git --tags"
}
```

So finally I manage my code like this in my pipeline.

But now it throws me bad url error [Bad URL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCTyE.png), I tried the same url with command prompt and it works fine.

Comment: didi you manage to fix it?

Comment: Yes, @MarceloFilho. I managed that. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind to share how did you do that?

Comment: I would love to @MarceloFilho, I just answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

On request for the answer to the situation I faced.

Please find the screenshot, which can help to push tags using **Git Publisher**.
Here *SERVICE_NAME & DEPLOY_FOR* are just pre-defined properties.
[image: Git publisher]

Comment: So are you not using Groovy Script? :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but at the first stage, I was also architect my project in such a way. But after that, I found out ways using which my project run as smooth and custom as in a groovy way.